# Problema al acceder a resultado de consulta en codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('documentos.titulo_principal,documentos.descripcion,autores.nombre,areas.nombre');
$this->db->from('documentos');
$this->db->join('documento_area', 'documentos.id_documento = documento_area.id_documento');
$this->db->join('areas', 'areas.id_area = documento_area.id_area');
$this->db->join('documento_autor', 'documentos.id_documento = documento_autor.id_documento');
$this->db->join('autores', 'autores.id_autor = documento_autor.id_autor');
$this->db->join('documento_palabra', 'documentos.id_documento = documento_palabra.id_documento');
$this->db->join('palabraclave', 'palabraclave.id_palabra = documento_palabra.id_palabra');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Al visualizar su resultado es: stdClass Object ( [titulo_principal] => la biblia de java [descripcion] => sdfdsfsdf [nombre] => matemáticas ).

Pero cuando realizo la consulta directa desde sql me trae estos datos:
[image: Resultado consulta sql]

Alguien sabe que como puedo traer del campo "nombre" el resultado "JON". Ese resultado pertenece a una tabla llamada "autores".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdClass Object` no deja de ser un objeto iterable con atributos, no puedes tener dos atributos con el mismo nombre ya que el último sobreescribe al anterior. Podrías cambiar el nombre de la columna en una de las tablas, o cambiarle el nombre durante la consulta:

```
$this->db->select('
    documentos.titulo_principal,
    documentos.descripcion,
    autores.nombre,
    areas.nombre AS nombre_areas
');
```